# Menu has disappeared in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, gui

My menu has disappeared in QGIS modeleler. How can I get it back?

[image]

Comment: Restarting the QGIS also does not help?

Comment: No it didnt, I probably hit some keyboard shortkeys. I'll install a newer version

Comment: Using another/creating a new user profile does not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled OSGeo4W with QGIS 3.12.0 and installed 3.20.2 and the menu's back